# German translation

Tags: english-to-german

I came across this sentence:
"From Mainz to Frankfurt it is about fifty kilometers" is translated as
"Von Mainz nach Frankfurt **sind es** circa fünfzig Kilometer."

Help me understand why it is not: Von Mainz nach Frankfurt **es ist** circa fünfzig Kilometer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unlike in English, the number of the conjugated verb in German coupler phrases follows the predicative noun, if any.

> It is Helen and Marcus. — Es sind Helene und Markus.

So in your example it must be plural because the distance is different from **one** in whatever unit.

---

About the word order, it must be *sind es* instead of *es sind* because the first position in your example is already occupied by the adverbial *Von Mainz nach Frankfurt*.

Comment: "The number of the conjugated verb in German coupler phrases follows the predicative noun". That's not quite correct. Rather, if the subject or the predicative noun is in plural, the verb must be in plural. For example: "Diese drei sind ein Team". Here it it's the subject which determines the number of the verb.

Comment: @RHa that's irrelevant. Compare "von Mainz nach Frankfurt ist es nicht weit", "Von Mainz nach Frankfurt sind es 0,7 Stunden mit dem Zug", where Stunden is possibly Accustive or some other nonsense. Plural makes no sense with these semantics.